# Moving ordered list in border box near to the top of page?

Tags: css, list

I'm trying to move an ordered list to the top of page within the border box. I want the list to stay in the border box as I want to move it closer to the top line of box. Anyone have any tips on how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide us with your HTML & CSS?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a div for the border box. Create a div for the ordered list inside the div of the border-box. Then you can use the `<position>` tag for the list div which will make it move anywhere inside the border-box:

```
<div id="border">
    <div id="list"></div>
</div>

#list{
    position:relative;           
    bottom: 10px;        // to move the list to the top.
}
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>007 Nightfire | Missions</title>
</head>
<style type> 
h1 {
 font-size:45px;
 text-align:center;
}
body {
  background-color:#F0F8FF;
}
div.list {
  border-color:coral;
  margin-left:32%;
  margin-right:32%;
  padding:180px;
  border:2px ridge ;
}
</style>
<h1><u>Missions</h1></u>
<body>
<hr>
<div class="list">
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: This is the code of my document so far, I forgot to add it

Comment: yes, so just adjust your code to the code i mentioned above and it should work out fine, just add the positioning code in the list class and it should position itself at the top

Comment: Do you know how to just get the text to the top and not the border box? Here is the code I made some changes to:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>007 Nightfire | Missions</title>
</head>
<style type> 
h1 {
 font-size:45px;
 text-align:center;
}
body {
  background-color:#F0F8FF;
}
div.list {
  border-color:coral;
  margin-left:32%;
  margin-right:32%;
  padding:180px;
  border:2px ridge;
  position:relative;
  bottom:5px;
}
</style>
<h1><u>Missions</h1></u>
<body>
<hr>
<div class="list">
<ol>
 <li>Paris Prelude</li>
 </ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: you have declared the class list incorrectly, it will just be .list{ all the styles} dont write the word div for declaration of class.